# Combine [FromBody] with [FromHeader] in WebAPI in .net Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

we are writing some API which required sessionId in header and some other data in body.
Is it possible to have only one class automatically parsed partially from header and from body?

Something like:

```
[HttpGet("messages")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(SessionHeaderKeyHandler))]
public async Task<ActionResult<MessageData>> GetPendingClockInMessages(PendingMessagesData pendingMessagesRequest)
{
    some body...
}
```

with request class like:

```
public class PendingMessagesData
{
    [FromHeader]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [FromBody]
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

I know, it is possible to do this, but it means, that I have to pass SessionId into the other methods as a parameter, instead of pass only one object. And we would have to do that in every API call.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MessageData>> GetPendingClockInMessages(
[FromHeader] string sessionId,
[FromBody] PendingMessagesData pendingMessagesRequest)
{
    some body...
}
```

Thank you,
Jakub

Comment: Do you want to fetch `SessionId` from header or query string parameter? If you want to fetch `SessionId`  from header, you can directly pull that value like `HttpContext.Request.Headers["SessionId"]` in controller and then you don't need to include `SessionId ` in `PendingMessagesData` class.

Comment: Yes, I can, but it seems to be better to do it automatically and pass it into PendingMessagesData. I would prefer this instead of separate reading headers and pass it as a parameter into some method. I would have to read this value in every API call and pass it into a service method as an extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> we are writing some API which required sessionId in header and some other data in body. Is it possible to have only one class automatically parsed partially from header and from body

1. Your `GetPendingClockInMessages` is annotated with a `[HttpGet("messages")]`. However, a HTTP GET method has no body at all. Also, it can't consume `application/json`. Please change it to `HttpPost("messages")`
2. Typically, `SessionId` is not passed in header of `Session: {SessionId}` like other HTTP headers. Session are encrypted via IDataProtector. In other words, you can't get it by `Request.Headers["SessionId"]`.

Apart from the above two facts, you can create a custom model binder to do that.

Since the Session doesn't come from header directly, let's create a custom `[FromSession]` attribute to replace your `[FromHeader]`

```cs
public class FromSessionAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata
{
    public static readonly BindingSource Instance = new BindingSource("FromSession", "FromSession Binding Source", true, true);
    public BindingSource BindingSource { get { return FromSessionAttribute.Instance; } }
}
```

And since you're consuming `application/json`, let's create a binder as below:

```cs
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly JsonOptions jsonOptions;

    public MyModelBinder(IOptions<JsonOptions> jsonOptions)
    {
        this.jsonOptions = jsonOptions.Value;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var type = bindingContext.ModelType;
        var pis = type.GetProperties();
        var result= Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var body= bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        var stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(body);
        var json = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
        try{
            result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, type, this.jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions);
        } catch(Exception){
            // in case we want to pass string directly. if you don't need this feature, remove this branch
            if(pis.Count()==2){
                var prop = pis
                    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) )
                    .Where(pi => !pi.GetCustomAttributesData().Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(FromSessionAttribute)))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                if(prop != null){
                    prop.SetValue( result ,json.Trim('"'));
                }
            } else{
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", $"cannot deserialize from body");
                return;
            }
        }
        var sessionId = bindingContext.HttpContext.Session.Id;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("sessionId", $"cannot get SessionId From Session");
            return;
        } else {
            var props = pis.Where(pi => {
                    var attributes = pi.GetCustomAttributesData();
                    return attributes.Any( ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(FromSessionAttribute));
                });
            foreach(var prop in props) {
                prop.SetValue(result, sessionId);
            }
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
    }
}
```

#### How to use

Decorate the property with a `FromSession` to indicate that we want to get the property via `HttpContext.Sessino.Id`:

```cs
public class PendingMessagesData
{
    [FromBody]
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }  // or a complex model: `public MySub Sub{ get; set; }`
    [FromSession]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, add a modelbinder on the action method parameter:

```
[HttpPost("messages")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPendingClockInMessages([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]PendingMessagesData pendingMessagesRequest)
{
    return Json(pendingMessagesRequest);
}
```

---

Personally, I would prefer *another* way, i.e, creating a `FromSessionBinderProvider` so that I can implement this without too much effort. :

```cs
public class FromSessionDataModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var sessionId = bindingContext.HttpContext.Session.Id;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(sessionId, $"cannot get SessionId From Session");
        } else {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(sessionId);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class FromSessionBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context)); }
        var hasFromSessionAttribute = context.BindingInfo?.BindingSource == FromSessionAttribute.Instance;
        return hasFromSessionAttribute ?
            new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(FromSessionDataModelBinder)) :
            null;
    }
}
```

(if you're able to remove the [ApiController] attribute, this way is more easier).